# ASP / SQL Server - If statement won't work

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript, conditional-statements

Struggling to display output of RS as a horizontal table.

I've a RS based on following SQL

```
SQL = "SELECT INTRAY.TEAM, Count(INTRAY.DOC_GUID) AS NumDocs " & _
"FROM INTRAY INNER JOIN DOCUMENT ON INTRAY.DOC_GUID = DOCUMENT.GUID " & _
"WHERE DOCUMENT.DOC_TYPE = 'PNEW' " & _
"AND DOCUMENT.DATE_RECEIVED > '"& Year(FromDate) &"-"& Month(FromDate) &"-"& Day(FromDate) &"' " & _
"GROUP BY INTRAY.TEAM, INTRAY.MAIL_STATUS, INTRAY.FILE_SYSTEM " & _
"HAVING INTRAY.MAIL_STATUS = 'NT' AND INTRAY.FILE_SYSTEM ='B' " & _
"ORDER BY INTRAY.TEAM ;"
```

I display results in a normal table, as below

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Records</th>
    </tr>
<%Do While Not RS.EOF %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=RS("TEAM")%></td>
        <td><%=RS("NumDocs")%></td>
    </tr>
<% RS.MoveNext
Loop%>
</table>
```

The resutls display normally in a vertial table. 10 records are returned, sorted by Team. OPS1, OPS10, OPS2 etc.

Note that 10 comes after 1 due to alpha sorting, don't know how to amend this.

There are only ever 10 teams that could be in the output, but sometimes not all will have a result, so the table could only return say, 2 or 3 teams.

I want to create a table which has hard coded column headings for each possible team (1 - 10), and then the next row being the output values for NumDocs

Team    1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

Results 8  4   7  17 4  87 20 19 1  7

So, I then close the recordset, and re-open it;

```
<%RS.Close%>
<br>

<%
RS.cursortype=adOpenKeyset
RS.Open SQL, IConn, 3, 3
RS.MoveFirst
%>
```

And write the table;

```
<table border=1>
<th>Report</th>
<th>OPS1</th>
<th>OPS10</th>
<th>OPS2</th>
<th>OPS3</th>
<th>OPS4</th>
<th>OPS5</th>
<th>OPS6</th>
<th>OPS7</th>
<th>OPS8</th>
<th>OPS9</th>
<tr>
<td>Untouched New Records (total)</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS1" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS1")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS10" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS1")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS2" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS2")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS3" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS3")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS4" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS4")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS5" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS5")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS6" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS6")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS7 " Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS7")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS8" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS8")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
<td>
<%If RS("Team") = "OPS9" Then %>
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
Else Response.Write("Not OPS9")
RS.MoveNext
End If %>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It won't work, all I get it 'Not OPSx" in the output.

The If Test is not working.

If I amend each cell to

```
<% Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
RS.MoveNext  %>
```

Then it will write the value, but I need to test for the value of TEAM in that row in the RS, and if I amend this to

```
<% If RS("Team") = "OPS1" Then
Response.Write(RS("NumDocs")) 
End If
RS.MoveNext  %>
```

It won't work and writes nothing.

Any ideas why mty IF is not working? When I write the values of TEAM, they appear to be OK and don't have trailing spaces. The SQL Server won't accept a TRIM function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server may not accept `TRIM`, but it **should** accept `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`, such as:

```
SELECT INTRAY. RTRIM(TEAM), Count(INTRAY.DOC_GUID) AS NumDocs
```

If you don't want to trim in your SQL statement (which I suggest you do), you can always try trimming your `IF` statements like this:

```
<%If Trim(RS("Team")) = "OPS1" Then %>
```

If you do `<% Response.Write "!" & RS("Team") & "!") %>` of your data right now, I suspect you'll see something like:

```
!OPS1 !
```

Comment: Thanks, sorted it now! Also, I had the End If in the wrong place in the second table. Thank you again

Comment: @BenHamilton - if this answer helped you, it would be polite to mark the answer as accepted so other users know the question has been answered.